# How to aggregate the marks of all the subjects in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the collection with following data

```
 {
                    "_id": "SG01",
                    "name": "Pawan",
                    "marks": [
                        {
                            "English": 93,
                            "Maths": 90,
                            "Hindi": 89,
                            "Sci": 98
                        }
                    ],
                    "__v": 0
                }

  {
                    "_id": "SG02",
                    "name": "Dravid",
                    "marks": [
                        {
                            "English": 40,
                            "Maths": 67,
                            "Hindi": 56,
                            "Sci": 45
                        }
                    ],
                    "__v": 0
                }
  {
                    "_id": "SG03",
                    "name": "Kartik",
                    "marks": [
                        {
                            "English": 65,
                            "Maths": 77,
                            "Hindi": 80,
                            "Sci": 79
                        }
                    ],
                    "__v": 0
                }
```

I would like to perform the operation in which `marks` should be displayed as `total_marks` of a particular student.
As I'm newbie with mongo and know how to perform basic aggregation with sum but wasn't able to understand with arrays.. However I tried but failed to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$marks"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            marks: {
                $objectToArray: "$marks"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id :1,
            name: 1,
            total_marks: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$marks",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this.v"] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            name: { $first: "$name" },
            total_marks: { $sum: "$total_marks" }
        }
    }
])
```

Since your marks are stored as an object you should use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to get an array of subjects. Then you can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to sum all subjects for one student.

Comment: Thanks @mickl Sir...... Sorry to bother you again .... can you help me with finding average ..  I was doing this way  :     Average_price: { $divide: [{ $sum: "$total_marks"},4] }

Comment: @p_k: you have sum so you just need to divide it by the number of marks. You need $size and $divide to do that.